# How to force Wi-Fi adapter to use specific channel

Tags: linux, networking

I am trying to force the Wi-Fi adapter to use a specific channel while connecting to the access point which supports both 2.4 GHz and 5 GHz (WPA authentication).

I am using the following configuration:

OS: Raspbian
Model: Raspberry Pi 2 Model B
Wi-Fi Adapter: Edimax EW-7811UTC
Driver: 8812au

I also tried with a different Wi-Fi adapter: Asus USB-N53 using driver rt2800.

Tried with `iwconfig` which is giving `SET failed on device wlan0 ; Operation not supported`.

Also tried `wpa_supplicant`.

What extra arguments need to be given to the `wpa_cli` or `wpa_supplicant` utility so that the Wi-Fi adapter will connect only to the specific band?

Comment: Please note that this wifi adapter does not support  5GHz channels greater then 48 so maybe because of that it does not us 5GHz mode.

Comment: See also this question: [How to change wifi channel?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/541611/how-to-change-wifi-channel)

Answer (score 6):

1. look for your interface

   ```
   sudo iwconfig
   ```
2. look at your channels

   ```
   sudo iwlist {interface} channel
   ```
3. turn off wifi

   ```
   sudo iwconfig {interface} power off
   ```
4. set your desired channel

   ```
   sudo iwconfig {interface} channel {channel, ex. "23"}
   ```
5. set your desired frequency

   ```
   sudo iwconfig {interface} freq {frequency, ex. "5.00G"}
   ```
6. turn on wifi

   ```
   sudo iwconfig {interface} power on
   ```

Comment: sudo iwconfig {interface} power off seems to be used to change the power saving settings, not to turn off the wifi

Comment: The following sequence did the trick for me:

```ifconfig {interface} down;
iwconfig {interface} mode managed;
ifconfig {interface} up;
iwconfig {interface} channel {channel, ex. "23"};
ifconfig {interface} down;
iwconfig {interface} mode monitor;
ifconfig {interface} up```

Source: https://ubuntuforums.org/archive/index.php/t-1685960.html

Answer (score -1):

You can't do that. The channel is selected automatically in the 2.4 or 5GHz band because the channel depends on your router: The router selects a channel and your client simply uses it. There is no way for the client to tell the router "please switch to band 13".

The 2.4 and 5GHz bands are usually selected by the network name; your router should offer two WLAN names.

Comment: I found I needed to change the frequency in my router config to retain the change.